# How to make a page responsive that has horizontal scroll

Tags: responsive

My page has few vertical border lines and few horizontal divs but I can't seem to be able to make it responsive for 600px page, can someone tell me how to make a horizontal page responsive.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can Use media-query for make site responsive like this :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .div { display: block; ....}
}
```

According to device width and height, you can render specific css.
more info about media query is here : [MediaQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)